# Why does Perl think "0 but true" is a number?

Tags: perl, numeric

`Scalar::Util`'s `looks_like_number` seems to be the commonly suggested way to determine whether a string is a number.
 Why does it consider the string `"0 but true"` to be a number ?

```
use Scalar::Util 'looks_like_number';
print looks_like_number("0 but true");   # 1
```